# Обязательно ли все делать по правилам, если надо добавить всего пару мультиязычных фраз?

Tags: opencart, локализация

Есть коммерческий проект, дорабатываю его уже с год+, они мной довольны...
Сейчас и вроде доработка небольшая. 
но сама доработка не главное, а вопрос в языках. (сайт 2-язычный - ru\uk)
Интересно, если нужно пару фраз мультиязычных вставить, обязательно-ли ВСЕ делают по ПРАвилам: контроллер->lang->.tpl
я вот смог все запихнуть в .tpl, без контроллера...(в tpl уже есть идентификатор языка)
Насколько это правильно\неправильно, интересно услышать Ваше мнение?

Answer (score 4):

Одна из самых больших проблем в разработке ПО - это управление сложностью проекта. Собственно, большинство хороших практик нацелены именно на то, чтобы построить расширяемую архитектуру и вам не пришлось с кровью в глазах переписывать половину кода для того, чтобы реализовать какую-то дополнительную функциональность.

Поэтому ваше "правильно" делать так-то – это просто рекомендованная практика, которая позволяет удобно подойти к вопросу локализации.

При этом каждая такая практика имеет свою цену. На другом примере: существует паттерн репозиторий, который позволяет проводить юнит-тестирование (абстрагирование от базы), но в результате если вы делаете репозитории, то пишете больше кода. А если при этом вы не пишите тесты – то вы зря тратите время на реализацию дополнительных слоёв абстракции и лишний код.

Хотите ли вы платить такую цену? Иногда заранее известно, что проект не пойдёт на мировые рынки – и значит, вполне позволительно сэкономить на времени (а значит, и стоимости) разработки. Угадаете с требованиями – молодец, не угадаете – придётся потом заплатить за это дополнительным переписыванием кода.

Собственно, это как раз отличает программиста-середнячка от сеньора – понимание того, сколько стоит лишний слой абстракций и насколько он здесь нужен. А ещё для этого на крупных проектах держат бизнес-аналитиков, они тоже не зря свой хлеб едят.

Поэтому стоит ли по-быстрому, но неправильно втыкать строчку – это можно решать в каждом конкретном проекте, главное – осознавать цену решения. Вы же сами потом будете сидеть вечером допоздна, когда не уложитесь в дедлайн.

Моё мнение такое. Существует большой набор практик, которые идут "из коробки" во многих движках/фреймворках и лучше им следовать, потому что их стоимость достаточно копеечная, а потенциальные выгоды достаточно высоки.

Тем более, если вы пишете на какой-то CMS – то настоятельно рекомендуется следовать гайдлайнам этой CMS, потому что все специалисты, которые работают с этой CMS пишут одинаковый код и это сокращает издержки на разбор чужого кода.

Поэтому чем городить собственный велосипед и потом самому вспоминать, что и для чего было сделано – лучше делать по типовым шаблонам.